# What is a clyse?

Tags: vocabulary

I've been reading about the recent flooding in Somerset, and came across this:-

> Floodwater is removed from many of the moors of the Somerset Levels by
>   pumping stations, which were originally steam-powered. These were
>   superseded by diesel engines, and more recently by electric pumps. The
>   King’s Sedgemoor Drain is unusual in that it operates entirely by
>   gravity. Consideration was given to replacing Dunball **clyse** with a
>   pumping station in 2002...

This word doesn't appear in any online dictionary I can find; the nearest is *clysis*, meaning:-

> the administration of an enema.

which, whatever your views on Somerset, is probably not what is meant. There's a video of *[Monk's Lease Clyse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szKZeiN_4a4)* in action here. Which bit is the *clyse*?

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18479/8019 .

Comment: You might be interested in the Wikipedia page for [King's Sedgemoor Drain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King's_Sedgemoor_Drain), artificial drainage channel which diverts the River Cary in Somerset into the River Parrett at Dunball near Bridgwater. The *proper noun names* of three of the drainage inlets are *Dunball Clyse, Cowhouse Clyse, Monks Leaze Clyse*. The author uses the non-capitalised version several times to refer to those sluices and proposed extensions thereto. There's also *Greylake Sluice, Nythe Sluice,* etc. (he uses *sluice* for those, and all the other "generic" references).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [OED definition](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34929), it is a local/regional word that means the same as *clow*. There is only one attestation quoted, from Somerset:

> 1882   *Spectator 6 May 595*.   In the Reports of the Somerset Drainage Commissioners, the sluices and locks under their jurisdiction are called ‘Clyses’.

Obviously, [*clow*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34751) is not exactly a common word, either, but it does seem to be more common than *clyse*, with about thirty or forty attestations in two meanings (actually three, but one is noted as being obsolete and has a question mark, but no attestations—so slightly paraphrasing the entry numbers here):

> 1. A sluice or floodgate: ‘esp.  (a) The outfall sluice of a river or drain communicating with a tidal river and provided with flood-gates’.  (b) ‘A shuttle in the gates or masonry of a lock, which is raised to admit or discharge water; a similar arrangement by which the admission of water to the wheels of water-mills is regulated’. Peacock *Gloss. Manley and Corringham (N. W. Lincoln)*.
> 2. A sluice or sliding door for other purposes.

So a *clyse* would appear to be just a regional Somerset word for a sluice, basically.

It seems that *clow* is a false singular, based on an earlier form *clowes/clowis*. This was originally a singular itself (from Old English *clūse*, meaning ‘enclosure’, and related to ‘close’, both from the nominalised Latin passive participle *clausa* ‘closed’, from the verb *claudō* ‘to close’), but was reinterpreted as *clow* + plural *-es* around the 15th or 16th century.

*Clyse* is less certain: it appears to be from French *écluse* (same word as the Old English *cluse*), or perhaps it just represents a dialectical nonce rounding of the u in the Old English, yielding regional **clȳse* as a variant of *clūse*.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to "Wetland, Life in the Somerset Levels" by Patrick Sutherland and Adam Nicolson (1986). "The only means of preventing the sea-water rushing miles inland up the rivers are the great doors called clyses which were fixed across the mouth of the Brue at Highbridge as early as 1485... The clyse doors are the great Canute gestures of the Levels, the grandest of all efforts to shut the Levels off from the sea... It is the simplest of technologies: the pressure of the flood tide forces the clyse shut into the mitre of lock gates; and the ebb releases them. They are the clearest Levels image of separation, of sorting land from water."
One problem for the people of Somerset is that the Parrot estuary is too wide for clyse technology, so when the tide surges, it washes sea and fresh water back onto the land.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the origin of the word clyse. However, what a clyse does is a bit different to most sluices. The water coming off the Somerset Levels (such as down the King's Sedgemoor drain) is fresh water, not sea water. Nor is it tidal. Also the level of drains on the Somerset Levels is usually a bit below the high tide mark of the river. The estuary of the River Parrett at that point is tidal and mostly sea water. You don't want sea water going back up the drains into the Levels and affecting the land by adding salt. So a clyse is a sort of one-way valve that is regularly operated to allow excess fresh water out into the tidal river when the level in the river is below that of the drain, but does not allow sea water back up the drain into the Somerset Levels when the level in the river is above that of the drain.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that some dutchman worked on the SL some centuries ago. Being dutch there are, depending on the pronunciation of clyse, the words "kluis" en "sluis" that are old enough and both have meaning in civil engineering.
Wikipedia gives an expanded solution to OED and further reference.
Sluis (dutch) => Sluice (english => Clyse, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sluice. Clow does not ring a dutch bell.

Comment: So basically you're saying that "clyse" might be a Dutch-influenced spelling of "sluice"? How did you arrive at this conclusion (or am I misunderstanding you completely)? Also, (1) what does the "SL" in your first sentence mean, and (2) where does "Clow" enter the question at all?

Comment: @Martha, I think this answer is a kind of combined comment to the previous answers: SL is probably the Somerset Levels, and _clow_ is mentioned in my answer.